Clutch slave/ master cylinder, OK to get from junkyard?
Strictly new or junkyard sourced ok?
100-150k miles on junkyard vehicle.
Bad idea or what?

There's nothing inherently wrong with salvaged parts, I've used plenty in the past and I've never had an issue because I'm choosy. It all depends on condition. I've either pulled the piece off the car in the yard myself, or I've bought one off of a reputable supplier. In the case of any kind of hydraulic part, be it a master cylinder, brake caliper, motorcycle brake, etc. I would visually inspect it for leaks, rust and damage. That doesn't guarantee it's going to work, mind you.
The thing with getting a part like that off of a high mileage car is unless the part was replaced you are getting a part that is much closer to failure than a part from a newer car. You could find yourself in the same situation not that far down the road. If you are looking to save money I'd look for a part from a car with less miles. You could also maybe find a refurbished part, or buy a refurb kit - clutch master cylinders are not that complicated.

Hydraulic parts tend to go bad when sitting unused.
If the donor car ran until recently, go on. Check also the rubber sleeves that protect from water ingress. If no traces of corrosion or leak under them, the part is good.
On the other hand, depending on where you live, it may or may not be easy to get them (both your or the salvaged ones) recycled. Even when no workshop around does this as a regular service, rubber piston rings are more or less easy to replace.
